# Drupal 7: How to add tags to a new content type?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Newbie here!

I go to `Structure > Content types > Add content type` and create a new content type.

But how can I add tags to my new content type, just like when you go to `Content > Add content > Article`, you get the option to enter a title, **tags** and body.

How can I add the capability to add tags to my new content type?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Manage Fields page of your content type, add a new *Term Reference* field.  Set the widget to be *Autocomplete term widget (tagging)*.

When you get to the field settings you'll be given the option of which vocabulary to use for the tags (for the default Article content type this is usually Tags I believe).